# explode string multiple instances

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following string;

```
$string = '[PAGE][TITLE]Navigation Link 1[TITLE]Content Here[PAGE]';
```

my desired output is;

```
<div id="navigation Link 1">Content Here</div>
```

I thought I had done it with ;

```
        $array = explode('[PAGE]', $string);
        $result = $array[0];
        for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
            $title = explode('[TITLE]', $array[$i]);
            for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($title); $i++) {
                $result .= $i % 2 ? '<div id="' . $title[$i] . '">' . $array[$i] . '</div>' : $array[$i];
            }
        }
```

If someone could take a look at this that would be great. This has also got to work with multiple instances.
For example ;

```
$string = '[PAGE][TITLE]Navigation Link 1[TITLE]Content Here[PAGE] some text [PAGE][TITLE]Navigation Link 2[TITLE]Content Here[PAGE]';
```

Thankyou for looking at this and for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`preg_match_all()`](https://php.net/preg_match_all) to get desired content :

```php
$string = '[PAGE][TITLE]Navigation Link 1[TITLE]Content1 Here[PAGE] some text [PAGE][TITLE]Navigation Link 2[TITLE]Content2 Here[PAGE]';

$html = '';
if (preg_match_all('~\[PAGE\]\[TITLE\](.*?)\[TITLE\]([^[.]*)~',$string,$matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $k => $match) {
        $html .= '<div id="'.htmlentities($matches[1][$k]).'">'.htmlentities($matches[2][$k]).'</div>' . "\n";
    }
}

echo $html;
```

output:

```
<div id="Navigation Link 1">Content1 Here</div>
<div id="Navigation Link 2">Content2 Here</div>
```

Comment: thankyou so much! exactly what i was after, would you also be able to use this method if the string looked like this `$string = 'random text before [PAGE][TITLE]Navigation Link 1[TITLE]Content1 Here[PAGE] some text [PAGE][TITLE]Navigation Link 2[TITLE]Content2 Here[PAGE] random text after';`

Comment: Because I used preg_match_all, I suggest to split the your string before, using strpos, strrpos and substr with [PAGE].